# How to check if the user has a booking in the clicked event or not?

Tags: c#, sql

I am a new C# and ASP.NET developer. I am developing a simple intranet booking management system for my company. I want the system to check if the user has a booking before in the event or not.

I have the following database design:

```
Users Table: UserID, Name
Events Table: ID, Title, Description, Location, NumberOfSeats, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, IsActive
Booking Table: BookingID, EventID, UserID
```

What I did so far is checking the UserID (when the user clicks on Booking button) if it is in the Users Table or not. If not, he will be added automatically to the database. Now I want to check if he has a booking in that event or not by checking BookingDetails table but I don't know how to do that?

**Could you please help me in designing this condition?**

Here's my method for checking the username:

```
protected void checkUserID(string userID) {

        int eventID = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value);

        string NetworkID = userID;
        string Name = Service.(".......");
        string BadgeNo = Service("ffffff");
        string DepartmentCode = Service("ffffff");

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=RegistrationSysDB;Integrated Security=True;";

        //if the user is not in the system database, add him
        if (Security.isExisted(userID) == false)
        {
            //string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=RegistrationSysDB;Integrated Security=True;";
            string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Users (NetworkID, Name, BadgeNo, DepartmentCode) values (@NetworkID, @Name, @BadgeNo, @DepartmentCode)";

            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                //Open DB Connection
                conn.Open();

                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetworkID", NetworkID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", BadgeNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentCode", DepartmentCode);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the parameters on the SELECT command, here is the revised code below.

```
    string insertBooking = "INSERT INTO BookingDetails (EventID, NetworkID) values (@EventID, @NetworkID)";
    string selectCommand = "SELECT count(*) as UserBookings FROM BookingDetails WHERE NetworkID = @NetworkID AND EventID = @EventID";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        //Open DB Connection
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", eventID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetworkID", NetworkID);

            if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertBooking, conn);
                cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", eventID);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetworkID", NetworkID);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        //Close the connection
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Booking table has a foreign key of UserID

```
Booking Table: BookingID, EventID, UserID
```

You can get a count of records against a particular UserID and if the count is greater than `0` that means the user has the booking. Your query may be:

```
Select count(*) as UserBookings from Bookings where UserID = @UserID;
```

where `@UserID` is the `UserID` you want to compare with, and `UserBookings` will give you the count

Comment: Thanks for your help but how I will Know that he has a booking in the event that he clicked on it to book a seat in it or not?

Comment: well in that case you compare against the EventID as well, so your query should be : `Select count(*) as UserBookings from Bookings where UserID = @UserID and EventID = @EventID`, you just need to combine two conditions in that case, your booking table has everything

Comment: Thanks for your help and I really appreciate it. Could you please combine it with my above code? I know I am asking too much but because I am a new developer and I am struggling with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my updated question and code above?